# tvOS: UISearchController inside UITabBar menu bar does not bring(focus) tabbar

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard, tvos

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

_searchResultsController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SearchVC"];
_searchController = [[SearchResultsViewController alloc] initWithViewController:_searchResultsController];

_containerVC = [[UISearchContainerViewController alloc] initWithSearchController: _searchController];
//self.backgroundView.backgroundColor = self.view.backgroundColor;
_containerVC.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.backgroundView.backgroundColor = self.view.backgroundColor;
_searchController.view.backgroundColor = self.view.backgroundColor;

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: _containerVC];
[self.backgroundView addSubview:navigationController.view];
```

Comment: I want to focus on UITabBarItem under which I am adding searchController on menu button press (like all other TabBarItems)